# Is there an equivalent of Android rotation vector in iOS?

Tags: android, ios, api, orientation

With Android, there is the notion of [rotation vector sensor](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html#sensors-motion-rotate) to get the full orientation of a device in space.

Is there an equivalent with iOS? I do not want to have the screen orientation, but the full orientation of the device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On iOS [CoreMotion](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/coremotion/reference/coremotion_reference/_index.html), gives you access to all the device orientation sensors.  Magnetometer and Gyroscope readings can combined manually or automatically to give you a running picture of the device orientation.

Comment: Oh yes; it seems the direct equivalent is in CMAttitude.quaternion, isn't it?

Comment: I can't really speak to the mapping between `CoreMotion` and the Android sensor API's.  Generally speaking it gives you access to the attitude of the device in terms of yaw, pitch, and roll.

Comment: Ok; there are some differences in the reference frame, but it seems it was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7950096/devicemotion-relative-to-world-multiplybyinverseofattitude

Answer (score 0):

There is.. infact there are a few ways to do it, all rather simple:

see android documentation:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html

and particularly:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_position.html

Comment: I think he's actually using this currently and looking for the iOS equivalent.